# Spring 3.1 or Later @RequestMapping Consumes/Produces

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, media-type

I have a question in regards to the consumes and produces part of the `@RequestMapping`.  I have an endpoint that I want to accept both JSON and XML and return JSON when JSON is passed in and return XML when XML is passed in.  Is there anything special that I have to do to make this work?

Sample code is listed below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/something", method = PUT, 
                consumes = {APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, APPLICATION_XML_VALUE}, 
                produces = {APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
public SomeObject updateSomeObject(SomeObject acct) {
    return doStuff(acct);
}
```

Will this work the way I'm expecting or do I need two endpoints `updateSomeObjectXML` and `updateSomeObjectJson` to handle both cases?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The article from the Spring blog - [Content Negotiation using Spring MVC](https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc) - provides details on how content negotiation works with Spring MVC, in brief if you want the same endpoint to handle XML and JSON, your mapping is correct, to summarize from the article:

1. Use path extension - you can send a json to `/something.json` and xml to `/something.xml` and expect the same thing on the way back
2. Use the `Accept` header, use a value of `application/json` or `application/xml` and use `Content-Type` to specify the submitted media type.

Answer (score 12):

Short answer:
**Annotate the method with @ResponseBody, and the method parameter with @RequestBody, and it will work (no need for 2 methods).**

**Explanation**:
First, *produces and consumes attributes are used to [narrow the mapping types](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-consumes)*. By default the first HttpMessageConverter found, that matches the media type requested, will be used.

Second, *client requests a media type* by giving the media type in:
- *Accept request header*
- *URL sufix* (http: //....//some **.xml** => "application/xml" media type requested)
- *URL format parameter* (.../some?format=xls)

Third, **produces** in combination with **@ResponseBody** will produce the object in the requested media type (nice for GET requests, when you need to send something back to the client), and **consumes** in combination with **@RequestBody** will consume the object with the requested media type (nice for POST requests, when you need to get something from the client).

Four, **when @ResponseBody not used, HttpMessageConverters are not used**. Rather **ViewResolvers kick in** and produce a view (HTML, PDF...), and the return type should follow the rules that accompany ViewResolvers (check default view resolver and InternalResourceViewResolver for more).

Hope it helps.

Other sources:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#consumes--
http://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc

Answer (score 1):

Well,

consumes/produces takes `String[]` as a parameter (see [RequestMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) from Spring's documentation) so I believe it will work. You can also try `headers = "content-type=application/json,application/xml"`.

Comment: Ya. My question is how do you know which of the "produces" it will be producing at any given time. Is this configurable or is it automatic. And how does it automatically select? If I have it listed as a consumer for JSON, XML, and Plain text but a producer of JSON and XML, what type will it return when plain text comes in?

Comment: it will probably check what 'accepts' header was set to request and then use json/xml serializer from classpath.