# Am getting 415 unsupported media type error while sending form data to controller

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc

This is the jquery function which returns 415 media type not found error

```
$('#save').on('click',function(){
    alert("test");
    var data = JSON.stringify(jQuery('#form').serializeArray());
    console.log("data"+data);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "saveExpenses",
        data: JSON.stringify(jQuery('#form').serializeArray()),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: true,
        success: function(data){alert("Success");}
    })
})
```

and the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveExpenses",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveExpense(@RequestBody ExpensesSummary expenses, HttpServletRequest request,HttpSession session){
    System.out.println("first name"+expenses.getFirstName());
    String message = homeBankingDao.expenseSummary(expenses);
    request.getSession().setAttribute("message",message);
    return "login";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should have a look to produce and consume annotations and attributes.
Those posts may certainly help:

- [Multiple scenarios @RequestMapping produces JSON/XML together with Accept or ResponseEntity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26676613/multiple-scenarios-requestmapping-produces-json-xml-together-with-accept-or-res)
- [Spring 3.1 or Later @RequestMapping Consumes/Produces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26471225/spring-3-1-or-later-requestmapping-consumes-produces)
- [Spring Mvc and MediaType for consumes in @RequestMapping for a get rest request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32189152/spring-mvc-and-mediatype-for-consumes-in-requestmapping-for-a-get-rest-request)
- [Spring RequestMapping for controllers that produce and consume JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35123835/spring-requestmapping-for-controllers-that-produce-and-consume-json)

Or I don't get it...

**EDIT**:

- if the error (415) is thrown from your jquery function then you should certainly also define the "accept: application/json" thing in your original query. Cf. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066591/415-unsupported-mediatype-for-post-request-in-spring-application).
- If server-side, you should also check that Jackson is present in your libraries. Cf. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492325/post-json-fails-with-415-unsupported-media-type-spring-3-mvc).

Comment: i have tried with produce and consume annotation .but still the same.

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly I hope